# php file() method is not working in server

Tags: php, file, centos

I am using HTTP API in my application. When I am calling that URL using file() method it is working fine in localhost but not in server.

I am using centos server.

In Command prompt :

```
#telnet www.example.com
```

it is getting resonse throw terminal but not in browser

**Code :**

```
<?php 
 $url = "http://www.example.com";
 $arr = file($url);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($arr);
 echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Which HTML form? Did you even read the question?

Comment: Most likely `url_fopen_wrappers` are not enabled.

Comment: check your server configuration by using php_info() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have allow_url_fopen disabled on the server. Enable it to get your code to work.

Comment: I modified in php.ini file like
allow_url_include = On
Thank U Every One

Answer (score 0):

From php.net documentation:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen
>   wrappers have been enabled. See fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename.

And here is explanation about fopen wrappers: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen

Check your php.ini and find allow_url_fopen option. It should be enabled to use this functionality